# JQuery - ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an MVC Action Result that I'm trying to access from JQuery/Ajax in my View. Normally, I have no problem with getting a json list of items and putting them in a dropdownlist with something like this:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item)
{
    items += "<option value=\"" + item.code + "\">" + item.activity + "</option>";
});
```

But this result is just one item.

What do I put in the following section to return the item `success: function (data) {}`?

Comment: There's not enough information here to provide a meaningful answer.  Can you show your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

Value is optional, and if you don't use it then the Text is submitted on post.

Or, you could put the Text in both value and in the text.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can use the 'data' argument directly:
return data.code;